# Outlook 2013, Search and then move the results to a particular folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013

Win10 Pro/64, Outlook 2013 (Not 365), On Premise Exchange Server 2012

I search for a value and Outlook returns about 200 emails.  I can select multiple emails in various ways, but can only move one message at a time.  This is going to be done many times and ongoing.  Perhaps a better way or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

What's your search scope? Current folder? When testing on my side, this seems only works under Current Folder. Please check whether this is the case for you.

Do you drag and drop? What if we click "Move" under Home tab?

If the issue occurs when searching current folder, we may [create a new .ost file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253).